# directory tree creation programmatically in android 10 (SAF)

Tags: android

I would ask if there is a way to create a directory tree (sdcard/path/to/something) in android without the user's interaction. 
I'm able to create directory launching intent with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, but I don't want the dialog used to choose device. 
Can I pass the path (uri) where creare my directories? Does exists a way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want the dialog used to choose device

Then you need to stick to locations on the filesystem that your app has rights to use, such as `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDirs()`. Or, if you content is a form of media, use the `MediaStore`.